# Extracting values from strings with repeating structure

Tags: string, r

Let's say I have a vector of strings, like this:

```
vectorOfStrings <- c("Name: Andrew, College: Bradford",
                     "Name: Charlie Daniels, College: Easton College",
                     "Name: Frank Gehry, III, College: Highlands University")
```

where there is a clear repeating "Name: ", ", College: " pattern.

I would like to produce a list (or data.frame) that looks like this:

```
listOfValues <- list(c("Andrew", "Charlie Daniels", "Frank Gehry, III"),
                     c("Bradford", "Easton College", "Highlands University"))
```

What is the most straightforward way to get from `vectorOfStrings` to `listOfValues`? I am reasonably familiar with the `base` string manipulation functions, as well as with `stringr`, but I would imagine this is a relatively common situation, and am hoping that there is a relatively well-developed solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible solutions:

**(1) strapplyc** The `mat` statement creates a matrix whose first column holds the names and whose second holds the colleges.  Then we convert that to an unnamed list in the last statement:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "Name: (.*), College: (.*)"
mat <- strapplyc(vectorOfStrings, pat, simplify = rbind)

unname(as.list(as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

**(2) gsub/read.table**  A variation using only plain R is to use `gsub` with `pat` from above to convert each input string to a pipe-separated string containing the data but not the tags.  Reading that in with `read.table` gives a data frame, `DF`.  Finally, we convert `DF` to an unnamed list:

```
g <- gsub(pat, "\\1|\\2", vectorOfStrings)
DF <- read.table(text = g, sep = "|", as.is = TRUE)

unname(as.list(DF))
```

ADDED: second solution

Answer (score 3):

I like mathematical coffee's idea, but since I've already got this written up, here's another possibility:

```
X <- strsplit(vectorOfStrings, ",\\s*(?=College:)", perl=TRUE)
do.call(rbind, lapply(X, function(X) gsub("(Name|College):\\s*", "", X)))
#      [,1]               [,2]                  
# [1,] "Andrew"           "Bradford"            
# [2,] "Charlie Daniels"  "Easton College"      
# [3,] "Frank Gehry, III" "Highlands University"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(unlist(
            strsplit(vectorOfStrings, "Name: ")), ", College: "))

       [,1]               [,2]                  
  [1,] "Andrew"           "Bradford"            
  [2,] "Charlie Daniels"  "Easton College"      
  [3,] "Frank Gehry, III" "Highlands University"
```

---

it seems there is lots of good answers already.  Similar to @Josh O'Brien, I would use strsplit.

Since you are not keeping `"Name"` and `"College"`, you can split right on it. Then you just wrapt that in a `do.call(rbind, ___)`  which will automatically drop any empty strings created by the split.

Answer (score 1):

I do this sort of thing with `regexp`, using `perl=T`) (haven't found a nice way to extract captured groups otherwise):

```
m <- regexpr('^Name: *(.+), *College: (.+) *$',
             vectorOfStrings, perl=T)
# m looks like this:
# [1] 1 1 1
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 31 46 53
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"capture.start")  # one column per capturing bracket,   
# [1,] 7 24               # one row per entry in vectorOfStrings
# [2,] 7 33
# [3,] 7 34
# attr(,"capture.length")    
# [1,]  6  8
# [2,] 15 14
# [3,] 16 20
# attr(,"capture.names")
# [1] "" ""

# laziness
st <- attr(m, 'capture.start')
en <- st + attr(m, 'capture.length') - 1
numCaptures <- ncol(st)

matches <- sapply(1:numCaptures, function (i) {
    return(substr(vectorOfStrings, st[, i], en[, i]))
})

# matches
#     [,1]               [,2]                  
# [1,] "Andrew"           "Bradford"            
# [2,] "Charlie Daniels"  "Easton College"      
# [3,] "Frank Gehry, III" "Highlands University"
```

Now massage `matches` into your desired form. I usually wrap this in a function as I use it fairly often.

You can even use Perl naming regex like so:

```
m <- regexpr('^Name: *(?<name>.+), *College: (?<college>.+) *$',
             vectorOfStrings, perl=T)
```

and then `attr(m, 'capture.names')` will be `c('name', 'college')` and `colnames(attr(m, 'capture.(start or length)'))` also be `c('name', 'college')`.

Anyhow the key seems to be using `perl=T`, or else `regexpr` doesn't return a set of start/end points per capturing bracket.

Comment: (alternatively, you could split on `:` and trim the values of preceding spaces or trailing commas and spaces, if you are certain that `:` will not appear internally in any of the names or colleges)

Answer (score 1):

probably simpler to use backreferencing

```
> vectorOfStrings
[1] "Name: Andrew, College: Bradford"                       "Name: Charlie Daniels, College: Easton College"       
[3] "Name: Frank Gehry, III, College: Highlands University"
> list(gsub('^Name:(.*), College:(.*)$',"\\1", vectorOfStrings) , gsub('^Name:(.*), College:(.*)$',"\\2", vectorOfStrings))
[[1]]
[1] " Andrew"           " Charlie Daniels"  " Frank Gehry, III"

[[2]]
[1] " Bradford"             " Easton College"       " Highlands University"
```